# Install Tensorflow 2.4 and opencv at the same time?

Tags: python, tensorflow, opencv, anaconda, conda

When I try to install opencv (4.01) using conda, it wants to downgrade my tensorflow from 2.4 to 2.1.  Is this a conda problem, or is it really not possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you can see [here](https://opencv.org/releases/page/3/), OpenCV 4.01 is from 2018, so it uses and old version of TensorFlow. You can try installing a more recent version of OpenCV, try updating your conda packages with `conda update` command or use `conda install -c conda-forge opencv`